# Merge all line starting with IF and ending with semicolon in shell script

Tags: shell, loops

i am stuck in below problem. I have done this with while loop and it is working fine but not able to omit the sequence number appended with string in each loop.

> i have a file content

```
1 SELECT abc from a ;

   2 .IF activi <> 1
   3 THEN 
   4 QUIT;
   5 .IF ERROR <> 0 THEN QUIT ERROR;
   6 SELECT 
   7 a,
   8 b,
   9 c
   10 FROM xyz;
   11 .IF ERROR <> 0
   12 THEN 
   13 QUIT ERROR;
```

> i want to edit in same file
>   with the following output

```
1 SELECT abc from a;    
   2 .IF activi <> 1 THEN QUIT ;
   5 .IF ERROR <> 0 THEN QUIT ERROR;   
   6 SELECT 
   7 a,
   8 b,
   9 c
   10 FROM xyz;    
   11 .IF ERROR <> 0 THEN QUIT ERROR;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
$ sed '/\.IF/{:a;/; *$/!{N;s/ *\n *[0-9]*//;ta}}' file
```

Output:

```
1 SELECT abc from a ;

   2 .IF activi <> 1 THEN QUIT;
   5 .IF ERROR <> 0 THEN QUIT ERROR;
   6 SELECT 
   7 a,
   8 b,
   9 c
   10 FROM xyz;
   11 .IF ERROR <> 0 THEN QUIT ERROR;
```

**Explanation:**

```
sed '
/\.IF/ {                   # for lines containing ".IF"
    :a;                    # define a "a" label for upcoming loop
    /; *$/! {              # if line does not contain ";"
        N;                 # add next line to pattern space
        s/ *\n *[0-9]*//;  # remove newline and leading digits
        ta;                # loops to label "a" if ";" is not found
    }
}' file
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. if possible can you explain please. It would be much easier for me to understand how it works.

Comment: @Kenavoz Thank you for your explanation. It help me a lot